# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que cuando el usuario ingrese un campo numérico en blanco, la variable sea tomada como valor 0?

Tags: python, variables

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Vi varios post del foro pero ninguno que haya visto me pudo solucionar el problema. Yo tengo un código en el cual el usuario ingresa dos valores y se suman, algo muy básico. Pero como recién estoy empezando eh intentado aplicar un condicional que lógicamente funciona pero me sigue tirando el mismo error.

El siguiente es mi código:

```
num2 = float(input())
if not num2:
    num2 = 0
```

El error que me tira es el siguiente:

[image: Imagen del error]

Cualquier ayuda será agradecida. Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

input te devuelve una secuencia de caracteres, tu estas buscando un valor de tipo float. Cuando intentas parsear la cadena ' ' te da un error debido a que no hay ningún número flotante que se pueda interpretar.

Puedes probar algo como esto:

```
num2 = float(input() or 0)
```

De esa manera ignoraras el valor `''` e interpretara 0 como float 0 => 0.0.

Si lo que quieres es el valor 0 en vez de 0.0, basta con intercambiar float por int.

Comment: Funciono a la perfeccion. Muchas gracias Sergio.

Comment: Buena alternativa sin embargo soluciona el problema a medias. Aún es posible ingresar espacios y terminar con un error, para solucionarlo bastaría con agregar `strip` de esta manera `num2 = float(input().strip() or 0)`

Answer (score 1):

La forma correcta es usando un `try ... except`.

La función `float` (`int` también) falla cuando intentas convertir algo que no es numérico, produciendo una excepción `ValueError`.

Entonces, la función `ingresar` pide un valor e intenta convertirlo de cadena a flotante dentro de un `try ... except`.

Si la conversión tiene éxito, la función retorna el valor.

Si la conversión falla, se produce la excepción que es captura con `except ValueError`. En tal caso, devolvemos un cero.

```
def ingresar(mensaje):
    entrada = input(mensaje)
    try:
        valor = float(entrada)
    except ValueError:        
        valor = 0
    return valor

x = ingresar("Deme un valor numérico ")
print(x)
```